# Dificuldade para obter informações atraves de Expressões Regulares

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Estou tendo dificuldades para obter uma informação utilizando `preg_match_all`.

Estas informações estão sendo retiradas de um código HTML de uma página da intranet, porém das informações que preciso, estou conseguindo coletar somente uma.

Segue um pedaço do código onde constam as informações:

```
        <img src="../../../img/prioridade_normal.png" style="vertical-align:middle;" width="20" height="20" align="top" border="0" title="Solicitação: Mudança de sala dentro da Gerência.&#13;Atribuição: Ponto de rede em cabeamento estruturado/Ativação/Instalação/">

                      </td>
                      <td width="20">

                            <img src="../../../img/alocacao_outro_profissional.png" style="vertical-align:middle;" width="20" height="20" align="top" border="0" title="Alocado para Tecnico 1" >

                      </td>
                      <th  scope="col" class="textoAtendimentoBranco" style="vertical-align:middle;">
                      <strong>19445/2015</strong>:2
                      </th>
```

As informações que preciso estão entre as tags `<title>`, no qual estou conseguindo capturar. O que não estou conseguindo é coletar a informação que esta entre `<STRONG> </STRONG>`.

A código que estou utilizando para recuperar estas informações:

```
 preg_match_all("/title=\"(.*)/", $url, $conteudo);
```

Minha dificuldade está em como fazer para também recuperar o que está entre `<STRONG>` na mesma Expressão regular que está sendo utilizada para o `<title>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acerte para :

```
preg_match_all("/title=\"(.*)\"|<strong>(.*)</strong>/", $url, $conteudo);
```

Comment: ha vais tentado desta forma, porem semresultado. Para utilizar assim tenho que inserir um quebra "\" na tag </strong> ficando assim: 
    preg_match_all("/title=\"(.*)|<strong>(.*)<\/strong>/", $url, $conteudo);
mas não esta trazendo o conteudo desejado.

Comment: mas o que ele ta trazendo para você? Qual o conteudo desejado? No regex Tester funcionou, estranho, qual ta sendo o problema de retorno ae?

Comment: não me traz o que esta entre as tags de <STROONG>, que usando o codigo acima, deveria ser 19445/2015

Comment: consegui fazer o ajuste necessario e agora esta retornando o valor desejado, mas tambem esta trazendo outras informações que tambem estão entre as tags <STRONG>. Tens como restringir o retorno de valor numerico. Só me interessa o que contiver numero. O que deve acrescentar na ER para isso?